# Invalid size when Initializing Vector4f

Tags: c++, eigen, ros, pcl

When I try to run [this line](https://github.com/baberjunaid/LiDAR_Tracking_3D/blob/main/src/Track_3D.cpp#L188) in ROS / PCL

```cpp
Eigen::Vector4f normalized(3,1);
```

I get the following Error:

```
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:281: 
void Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Derived>::resize(Eigen::Index, Eigen::Index) 
[with Derived = Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>; Eigen::Index = long int]: 
Assertion 
`(!(RowsAtCompileTime!=Dynamic) || (rows==RowsAtCompileTime)) && 
(!(ColsAtCompileTime!=Dynamic) || (cols==ColsAtCompileTime)) && 
(!(RowsAtCompileTime==Dynamic && MaxRowsAtCompileTime!=Dynamic) || 
(rows<=MaxRowsAtCompileTime)) && (!(ColsAtCompileTime==Dynamic && 
MaxColsAtCompileTime!=Dynamic) || (cols<=MaxColsAtCompileTime)) && rows>=0 && cols>=0 &&
 "Invalid sizes when resizing a matrix or array."' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I'm using Ubuntu `20.04`, Eigen `3.3.7`.

Can you please tell me how can I solve that? thanks in advance.

Comment: You're initializing a `Vector4f`, meaning a vector with 4 rows and 1 column. You pass parameters telling it to allocate 3 rows, 1 column. That's the mismatch

Comment: BTW: Looking at the code in your github, the whole function can be rewritten as `return normal.normalized();`

Comment: or if you want to continue ignoring the 4th element, then `Eigen::Vector4f rtrn; rtrn.head<3>() = normal.head<3>().normalized(); return rtrn;`

Comment: @Homer512 indeed `normal.normalized();` solved my problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution as explained by @Homer512 is:

```cpp
normal.normalized();
```